# Counting bit sequences

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

Suppose we are to count bit sequences of length $n$ s.t the sequence doesn't contain 3 consecutive 1's

If $P(n)$ is the number of such sequences, is the equality $P(n) = P(n-1) + P(n-2) + P(n-3)$ valid?

If not how do you formulate it recursively?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes, the offset [Tribonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers) and [OEIS A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073)

Comment: @Henry Okay, thanks!!